# Is there any command to count the length of rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, string-length

Having a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), date1 = c("2014-Dec 2018","2009-2010","Jan 2009-Aug 2010"), date2 = c("Feb 2016-Dec 2018","2014-Dec 2018","Oct 2013-Dec 2018"))

  id             date1             date2
1  1     2014-Dec 2018 Feb 2016-Dec 2018
2  2         2009-2010     2014-Dec 2018
3  3 Jan 2009-Aug 2010 Oct 2013-Dec 2018
```

Is their any command which could check in every row if their is something different than this format "Jan 2009-Aug 2010" and keep it into a new dataframe? Meaning that check if there are 17 charcters including the spaces between month and year.

Example of expected output

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), date1 = c("2014-Dec 2018","2009-2010"), date2 = c("Feb 2016-Dec 2018","2014-Dec 2018"))
  id         date1             date2
1  1 2014-Dec 2018 Feb 2016-Dec 2018
2  2     2009-2010     2014-Dec 2018
```

Comment: Read about nchar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A safest option could be to `split` your data and use `grepl` to check whether the date respects the format:

```r
pattern = "[A-Za-z]{3} \\d{4}-[A-Za-z]{3} \\d{4}"
split(df, rowSums(sapply(df[-1], grepl, pattern = pattern)) == 2)
```

output

```r
$`FALSE`
  id         date1             date2
1  1 2014-Dec 2018 Feb 2016-Dec 2018
2  2     2009-2010     2014-Dec 2018

$`TRUE`
  id             date1             date2
3  3 Jan 2009-Aug 2010 Oct 2013-Dec 2018
```

**Explanation**

The pattern is not that complicated: three `{3}` letters `[A-Za-z]` followed by 4 digits `\\d`, twice, and separated with `-`.

Comment: Is it possible to include in the regex the missing values if they exist in a specific column?

Comment: If the NA is for dates like `2009-2010`, then there is no problem. In other cases it might be a problem; can you edit your question to add this case?

Answer (score 1):

Check the number of characters for all dates, then check if there are less than 2 per row:

```
df[ rowSums(sapply(df[ -1 ], nchar) == 17, na.rm = TRUE) < 2, ]
#   id         date1             date2
# 1  1 2014-Dec 2018 Feb 2016-Dec 2018
# 2  2     2009-2010     2014-Dec 2018
```

Comment: thank you. If there are missing values in the cells how is there any way to include it in the command, as it keeps all the rows and it could not identify those without it

Comment: @ErikBrole remove them before summing, see edit. I prefer Mael's answer with regex, it is safer.